# Alternate model name in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a `house` model giving route like

```
/house/:id
```

In some cases, I would (or the user, in a very dynamic way) that a house is cabin, cottage, building, farm, etc, out of a predefined list. The selection is made depending on what the user inputs, without letting the user choose, so it depends on logic which can change

Is there a way to create alternate route that if the logic decides that the house is a cabin that it will have routes of

`/cabin/:id`

that will route it to the houses controller and the appropriate action? (same for other alternate names)

I can't use STI since the instance is a house, and can change its 'type' dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

in your routes

```
resources :house
resources :cabin, :controller => "houses"
resources :cottage, :controller => "houses"
resources :building, :controller => "houses"
```

run `rake routes` and make sure if it works as expected